# android application force close while start

Tags: android, android-emulator

Trying to develop hello world, but getting force close error on emulator. thanks in advance

```
07-25 12:04:12.308: D/AndroidRuntime(277): Shutting down VM
07-25 12:04:12.308: W/dalvikvm(277): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.exampe.helloww/com.exampe.helloww.HelloActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.exampe.helloww.HelloActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.exampe.helloww-2.apk]
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.exampe.helloww.HelloActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.exampe.helloww-2.apk]
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
07-25 12:04:12.368: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  ... 11 more
07-25 12:04:17.158: I/Process(277): Sending signal. PID: 277 SIG: 9
```

Comment: have you declared your activity in manifest?

Comment: @Shrikant if just added a new project with Eclipse, it should have done it by it´s own.
pawarrohit14 could you please, post some of the code? Or add a little bit more of info, like, if you created the project from scrach or with Eclipse Wizard.

Comment: post your AndroidMenifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `ClassNotFoundException` is usually caused when you try to run your app on lower sdk version than the target sdk

Comment: How do you figure? I mean, it is not a system class or anything (`com.exampe.helloww.HelloActivity`)

Comment: @mihail please verify your answer, because is any APK can't install if it is not compatible for that device, There is also minimum SDK value

Comment: check your manifest first. If the MinSdkVersion is lower than the TargedSdkVersion, then you may use some classes that are not available in the lower Sdk. For example, the Base64 decoding is available since SDK=9, if you try to use it on SDK=8 you will get ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: @Android Coader, you have MinSdkVersion and TargetSdkVersion. The most simple example is the use of the AdMob plugin - it require SDK=11, but this does not mean that  you can't run them on SDK=8

Comment: maybe sounds strange but I really had this experience and the only thing I got in the log was ClassNotFoundException: myClass. After step by step debug I figured out it was caused by the Base64 class. I have no idea why the error log looked like that

Comment: my MinSdkVersion is 8 and TargetSdkVersion is 15. so what should i do

Comment: I'd chacge the TargedSdkVersion to 8.

Answer (score 0):

Add your HelloActivity in Manifest file.Due to this your Activity is not found and you are getting ClassNotFoundException as

E/AndroidRuntime(277): Caused by: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:` `com.exampe.helloww.HelloActivity`